# Duplicates value on record, on Upsert. Upsert shouldn't cause duplicate check?

Tags: apex, rest-api, upsert

We have a pipeline built for moving data from our custom app through Mulesoft (Anypoint).

The Mulesoft app is utilizing the Mule-provided Salesforce Connector, and we're performing single Upsert calls (batch will be coming, but we wanted to see how the process works in isolation).

What is interesting is that I receive errors that a record is duplicated. In this case, `External_Interview_ID__c` is an External Id marked unique. In the API call, we are passing that field as the external identifier.

`duplicate value found: External_Interview_ID__c duplicates value on record with id: a0mEX000000B891 DUPLICATE_VALUE`

I have seen this when doing a bulk insert due to how Salesforce processes records, but never in a single call.

This behavior doesn't occur for *every* call, so it's been challenging to pinpoint the specific issue.

Has anyone come across something similar?

Comment: Not sure why the downvote. I'm seeing behavior that is not to be expected and requested help. Provided context into the question, background, and steps.

Comment: Some people just DV and leave. Here's a +1, I think it's well-defined enough considering you have no idea what's going on. What's the specific ID value? Have you checked in the database to see if there might somehow be multiples?

Comment: the external ID value is a standard UUID `7156188d-33dd-478c-9bf6-05fbf2d5072a` for a field entitled `External Interview ID` I looked and there's no other duplicates with that UUID across any object (thought it might conflict with another object). 
The behavior occurs with 2 other objects so it's not just isolated to the one object or one record